# Deoplete with Neovim doesn't work

Tags: autocompletion, neovim, plugin-deoplete

I have a problem with my deoplete plugin.
When I write code, I don't have automatic completion on dot. I need to manually press `<c-x><c-o>` to make it work.

Here is my deoplete configuration:

```
let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1
let g:deoplete#delimiters = ['/','.']
let g:deoplete#sources#go = 'vim-go'
let g:deoplete#keyword_patterns = {}
let g:deoplete#keyword_patterns._ = '[a-zA-Z_]\k*\(?'
```

Here an exemple on "automatic" completion:
[image]

Then, when I press `<c-x><c-o>` :

[image]

I really don't know how to get the second case.

p.s: I read so many tutorials on the web and I have already searching on the stackexchange without finding.

Comment: Run `:CheckHealth` to find problems.  You also need [deoplete-go](https://github.com/zchee/deoplete-go).

Comment: You answer solve my problem. How can i up vote your remark?

Comment: No need.  If you want to, show support for Neovim, deoplete, and deoplete-go by starring their repos on GitHub :]

Comment: @hallow_me you can answer your own question

Comment: @TommyA, I think a better place to put answers is in, wait, let me think, ..., an *answer!* Have moved your comment to an answer box, and made it CW so I can't be accused of rep-whoring :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Works for me

Answer (score 1):

You can run `:checkhealth` (`:CheckHealth` in older versions) to find any problems.

You also need [deoplete-go](https://github.com/zchee/deoplete-go).